# Got confused on the "Site Creation" options which we have inside SharePoint online administration settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, site-creation, office-365-groups

I am working on SharePoint online tenant, and I want to allow end-users (non-admin users) to be able to create and manage their own site collections. so inside my SharePoint Online admin site, I found the following setting for site creation:-

- A site that uses one of the new team site or communication site templates, or a classic site
- A site that uses one of the new team site or communication site templates
- A classic site

As follow:-

[image]

and I read the following link about these options:-

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-site-creation-in-sharepoint-online-e72844a3-0171-47c9-befb-e98b23e2dcf9

But I am a bit confused on what are the differences between the above 3 options for creating sites? Mainly I have these issues:-

1. What are the differences between Team Site and classic site ? as when I create a new site collection using SharePoint admin user, I got this option, so to me team site is the same as the classic site:-

[image]

2. now in the description of these options they mentioned the following "**Use this option to let users who don’t have permission to create a group still create classic sites**". so what is "Create Group" permission? is it a permission that the user can be granted inside SharePoint? or inside Office 365?
3. now currently we have the above options for the Site Creation (as shown in the first picture). But I login using an end user account, to our root site collection. but I can not find any link or area I can create a site using the end user ? although inside the above setting we mentioned that users can create either Team or communication sites OR a classic site if the user does not have "Create Group" permission..

so can anyone advice on the above settings?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Team Site is a **modern** team site. And the **group** mentioned in article is **Office 365 group**.

Sign in Office 365. In the top left corner of the page, select the app launcher icon and then select the **SharePoint** tile. If you don't see the **SharePoint** tile, click the **Sites** tile or **All** if **SharePoint** is not visible. At the top of the **SharePoint** page, click **+ Create site** and choose the Team site option. It is a **team site** with an **Office 365 Group**.

[image]

Based on your screenshots, you are using the classic site creation experience. In this case, a corresponding Office 365 Group won't be created.

For more information about a team site in SharePoint Online, see [Create a team site in SharePoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-team-site-in-SharePoint-Online-ef10c1e7-15f3-42a3-98aa-b5972711777d).

For more information about Office 365 Groups, see [Learn about Office 365 groups](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-about-Office-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2).

Comment: now inside my App launcher there is not any tile for SharePoint or for Sites or All tile, I only get tiles for (security and compliance, Store, admin, etc..). second point , if I am using classic site creation experience, then how I can switch it the modern (or non-classic experience) , so I can create modern team sites?

Comment: third point, also how we can assign the "Create office 365 group" permission  to the users? as in the "Site Creation" options it is mentioned the following `"Use this option to let users who don’t have permission to create a group still create classic sites". `.. so which permission they are referring to ? and how we can assign it to the related users ?

Comment: have you read this article: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-team-site-in-SharePoint-Online-ef10c1e7-15f3-42a3-98aa-b5972711777d